# Showing how many form checkboxes are checked in document itself

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have coded an ASP page using an example here that shows how many checked boxes there are in a form in a pop-up alert box. The problem is that we now have so many boxes on the form that it takes forever to select a box, close the alert,  check another box, close the alert… I would like to change or replace the code to show the number of checked boxes in the document's HTML instead of an alert, updating the count as boxes are checked or unchecked. Here is the script used to count the boxes and show the alert:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkTotalCheckedBoxes()
{
     var checkLength = 0;
     var boxes = document.getElementById("yyy").getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     {
         boxes[i].checked ? checkLength++ : null;
     }
     alert (checkLength + " boxes are checked." );
}
</script>
```

I also have a "Select All" script that works great for selecting all the boxes at once. The only problem is the "Select All" box stays checked once used, even if some of the boxes are de-selected. I need to modify the script to uncheck the "Select All" box is the user clicks it, then de-selects any of the checked boxes.

Here is that script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  } 

       var checkLength = 0;
     var boxes = document.getElementById("yyy").getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     {
         boxes[i].checked ? checkLength++ : null;
     }
     alert (checkLength + " boxes are checked." );
}
</script>
```

Many thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Instead of an alert why don't you place a label in the page and update the text to the label.

Comment: @Dean, That sounds like what I am looking for, but have never had to do so, therefore I'm at a loss of how to accomplish the suggestion. Can you please provide a code example or point me in the right direction? In the meantime, I'll try to find an example here of how to do so...

Comment: is jquery an option?

Comment: I don't have much  experience with JQuery, but yes, it is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing the HTML code, I can only guess what your page layout looks like.  That being said, look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yxo6de48/

It should provide you with a little guidance, if nothing else, on how to achieve what you are looking for.

Javascript:

```
function checkTotalCheckedBoxes()
{
     var checkLength = 0;
     var boxes = document.getElementById("yyy").getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     {
         boxes[i].checked ? checkLength++ : null;
     }
     document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = checkLength + " boxes are checked.";
}

function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
  for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  } 
  checkTotalCheckedBoxes();
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for, with the exception that the "Select All" checkbox stays selected if any of the other checkboxes are de-selected after it is used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a label:

```
 <label id="lblTest" />
```

Set the text:

```
  document.getElementById("lblTest").innerHTML(//value here);
```

or with jQuery:

```
 $("#lblTest").text(//value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!